# Testes Jasmine em arquivos separados sem quebrar o describe?

Tags: javascript, testes, bdd, jasmine

Quero organizar meus testes em javascript em arquivos separados, mas estes podem fazer parte de um modulo em comum. Por exemplo:

```
describe("Controllers", function () {

    describe('Move list Controller', function () {

        //ListController its
    });

    describe('Movie Detail Controller', function () {

        describe('must activate with', function () {
             //details controller its when activates
        });
        //other details controller's its

    });

    describe('Reserve Controller', function () {
         // reserve controller its
    });
});
```

Eu tenho o `describe('Controllers')`, e sob ele todos os controllers. Mas aqui já deu para ver a proporção que os arquivos vão tomar pois cada controller terá vários `its`. O que eu preciso é quebrar estes testes em um arquivo por `controller`, mas mantendo eles ainda como parte do `describe('controllers')`

Tentei chamar o mesmo `describe` em arquivos diferentes e ele gerou redundância:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia de como **separar em arquivos sem quebrar o `describe`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
var parte = ['descrição', fnction(){ /* os it's aqui */ }]; // podes importar de outros arquivos
```

e depois dentro de cada describe dentro do `describe('Controllers'` chamas estes outros describes com [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
describe.apply(null, parte );
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cttb6zzb/

```
var A = ['Parte A', function () {

    it('shoud pass the test A1', function () {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });
    it('should pass the test A2', function () {
        expect(2).toEqual(2);
    });
}];
var B = ['Parte B', function () {

    it('shoud pass the test B1', function () {
        expect('b1').toEqual('b1');
    });
    it('should pass the test B2', function () {
        expect('b2').toEqual('b2');
    });
}];

describe('Controllers', function () {
    describe.apply(null, A);
    describe.apply(null, B);
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, então eu separei um arquivo `describe.apply.js` só para fazer isso. Muito obrigado!